# Umbraco v5 dates?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, umbraco

we are starting a new project and I would like to know if V5 will be release soon, cause you know that MVC is way better than webform so I would prefer wait a little bit more and work with MVC than start now on top of 4.7 and work in webform but when I try to find any docs on umbraco v5 aka Jupiter it seems like it wont be in Beta before a while. I know that next week they have CodeGarden11 and they are supposed to talk a lot about Umbraco 5 but I don't find a lot of documentations except this for this link : http://jupiter.umbraco.org/

Anyone has more informations?

Thanks a lot!

Edit : I found this to use MVC with umbraco : http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/mvcbridge if it can helps anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umbraco v5 is over http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2012/6/13/v5-rip.aspx

stick with 4.X for now.

Comment: Yeah I know, it's sad here's 2 post on MVC in U4 : http://shazwazza.com/post/MVC-in-Umbraco-v4.aspx and http://www.aaron-powell.com/umbraco/using-mvc-in-umbraco-4

Answer (score 2):

Umbraco 5 RTM was released on 31 January 2012 (but discontinued shortly thereafter by the developers).

Answer (score 2):

Umbraco 5 has been cancelled but continues to live.  A small team of developers has forked the project:

http://www.rebelcms.com/